# How to race my way through Room 01 in Chapter 7 The Reunion?

Tags: portal-2

I gave the room a nice paint job, so the whole room and the corridor on the left are covered:

[image]

So I managed to reach the third room with the cubicle that I need in this room. But I'm having difficulties getting it into this room.

[image]

I tried making a portal behind the cubicle and 'throw' it through but that didn't work. But I can't figure out how to get the paint in that room... so I'm stuck. Any help?

Comment: Are you enjoying the game, @Ivo?  You seem to be having more trouble than I did... ;)

Comment: I'm having the time of my life @Shinrai ;-) But if I have to think about what to do, then I'm very sure others could use our help too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need paint for that one. Make a portal behind that cube, pull it out, then make a portal at the other end of the gap, walk through, then make another portal back into the main room.
[image: Portal set-up one]
[image: Portal set-up two]